# Can Pelican support multiple article indices in different templates?

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I'm trying to investigate if I can use Pelican to generate my site and having trouble seeing how to present two different lists of articles, each rendered in their own template.

My site has blog pieces, feature articles, and white papers. The index page for each of these needs to be rendered in a different style.

After a little playing around, it appears to me that I would probably need to have a category for each article-type. Is it possible to tell the engine to render each category list using a different template.

Alternatively, and perhaps better for increased flexibility, is it possible to create a `page` that loops through a category and i control the display of the article list? I could then solve the problem by creating a `page` of my own for each category. Does a page have access to the pelican `context` (i.e. the catalog of content built by the generators' `generate_context` methods)

Comment: How different are the styles? Is it the whole page that will differ, or just the article's block? You can certainly use `{% if category == '...' %}` to select e.g. different sub-templates. The short answer is yes, but the long answer is probably too long for SO!

Comment: If you don't want pagination, then yes you can do those. The [common variables](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.0/themes.html#common-variables) are available to all templates. So you get the full article list at any template and you can filter the ones you like. You can probably do that with `TEMPLATE_PAGES`, which I assume would be easier than a `Page`. If you want pagination, it's probably better to set a category to your articles and reuse the category output from `category.html` template. You can extend the template conditionally and use a different base like @jonrsharpe mentioned.